# Cache Busting Not Working? Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

Why does cache bursting not working for me without me hitting F5?

In my index.html that gets generated by webpack I have this javascript file(which contains my reactjs site)

Right now on production I have something like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.b2c9dad20992aaf2f272.js"></script></body>
```

I just built a new file and in index.html I have

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.087b578d2cde3ed8379f.js"></script></body>
```

Yet everyone I test it with keeps getting their cached version of the site. Most people I have access to are using chrome so I can't say if this is only a chrome thing or all browser thing.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome seems to be pretty enthusiastic about caching. I've pushed out a few updated js files that required multiple hard refreshes (Ctrl + F5) before Chrome decided to check for a new file.

Adding the following header to the server response caused a miraculous reduction in help desk tickets from users that needed to clear their cache.

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Comment: so this needs to be put on my server response? I am using asp.net core so not sure where to put that yet. Does must-revalidate check to see there is a new version if so use it otherwise use cached version?

Comment: Yes, that would be done in the web server settings. In IIS (I'm assuming, because asp.net), you can add the response header for all requests to the server or for a specific site.

Comment: Yes I am using iis, how would I do this?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Chrome sends the date it cached the file to the server and the server responds with the updated file if it has been modified after it was cached. (that's the basic gist of the process)

Comment: In IIS, you would add it to the HTTP Response Headers module.

Comment: So the modual area in iis?

Comment: If you could post a screenshot or tutorial on how to set it would be very helpful..

Comment: Tutorial can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954002/how-to-add-a-custom-http-response-header-to-a-web-site-that-is-hosted). Name: "Cache-Control", Value: "must-revalidate"

Comment: hmm, yesterday I tried that. I went and added that to the http response on my reactjs website and then restarted iis and asked a customer to try, but customer was still getting old cached version.

Comment: Use Chrome's Dev Tools to check if the header is working. In the Network tab, select the request for a script to see if the Status Code displays "200 OK (from disk cache)" or just "200 OK".

Comment: just want to double check "must-revalidate" do I enter it in with or without quotes.

Comment: No quotes in either box. Just added those to signify the values to enter.